# Why Provider is not giving the initialized value instead of expected one?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to display a  document field value from `firestore` and want to display it on other pages using the provider.

This is my code inside the provider file:

```
class UserState extends ChangeNotifier {
  
  String userName = 'default error';

   Future<void> getName() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      userName = (value.data()?[' uname'] ?? "Default userName");
      print(userName);
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here the correct `userName` value is getting printed using print statement, but when I try to pass it through the provider it is showing the initialized string value `default error` which I provided for null safety.
This is the screen where I want to display the variable userName :

```
class testscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const testscreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  _testscreenState createState() => _testscreenState();
}

class _testscreenState extends State<testscreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false).getName();
    final String name = Provider.of<UserState>(context).userName;
    return Scaffold(body: Text(name));
  }
}
```

How can I show the right value instead of initialized value for userName?What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some fixes in the code.

1. `notifyListeners()` are not waiting for the `fetch` to complete

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      userName = (value.data()?[' uname'] ?? "Default userName");
      print(userName);
      notifyListeners();  Try adding the notifyListeners() here
    });
  }
```

2. Remove the `provider()` call from within the bluid method

```
class testscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const testscreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  _testscreenState createState() => _testscreenState();
}

class _testscreenState extends State<testscreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false).getName(); Call getName here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Text( Provider.of<UserState>(context).userName));  Call it this way
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`notifyListeners` doesn't wait to finish the fetch. You can try

```dart
  void getName() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      userName = (value.data()?[' uname'] ?? "Default userName");
      print(userName);
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

Or

```dart
  Future<void> getName() async {
    final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get();
    userName = (value.data()?[' uname'] ?? "Default userName");
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

I will prefer using `Consumer` widget for this case.

---

You can also use initState to call the method.

```dart
class testscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const testscreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  _testscreenState createState() => _testscreenState();
}

class _testscreenState extends State<testscreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false).getName();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer<UserState>(// using consumer 
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return Text(value.userName);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Also you can call the method on constructor,

```dart
class UserState extends ChangeNotifier {
  String userName = 'default error';
  UserState() {
    getName();
  }
  Future<void> getName() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    userName = "Default userName";
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code like the above but the  print(userName); is getting printed continously .why?

Comment: Reading value inside `build` method(`Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false).getName();`), You can use FutureProvider for this or may FutureBuilder/Stream will also work